# regex get date august 22, 2016?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
some text August 22, 2016
```

I want to get the date only - `august 22, 2016`.

the date is always in the end of the string.

I tried something like this... but no success...

```
$date2 = preg_match('/\b(.*?)\b&\/\d{2},\b\/\d{4}$/', $string, $date2);

/\b(.*?)\b&\/\d{2},\b\/\d{4}$/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
'~\p{L}+\s*\d{2},\s*\d{4}$~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mV8zT3/1)

**Details**:

- `\p{L}+` - 1 or more letters
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\d{2}` - 2 digits
- `,` -  a comma
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `$`   - end of string.

Note that to precise this further, you may want to replace `\p{L}` with an alternation group enumerating all months, like `(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|June?|Jule?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)` that can further be improved/enhanced. To match XXth and XXIst centuries only, you may replace `\d{4}` with `(?:20|19)\d{2}`.

Comment: If you need more clarifications, just feel free to drop a comment here.